# Hyperledger Fabric v1.1 and Java Chaincode

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm working on a project that requires that I use version 1.1 of Hyperledger Fabric. Is it possible to plug Java chaincode in this version? I know Java chaincode started to be supported only in version 1.3 but is it possible to plug it in version 1.1? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that will not be possible. The peers spin up new docker containers to run the chaincode. If the peer is using the 1.1 docker image it will not be able to spin up a new java environment container to run the code.